# Getting DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN trying to make subdomain in Dreamhost

Tags: dns, subdomain, dreamhost

Website is abc.com, I made landingpage.abc.com, FTP'd some files in, clicked Visit in Dreamhost, and got DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error, page wouldn't load.

Please tell me what else I need to tell you to get an answer for this, if necessary.
Thanks in advance.